# Code coverage in Chromium browser's console is not updating, I can only see state on page load, not subsequent changes

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

This question is about "Code coverage" feature in chromium developer tools.

In chrome/chromium code coverage no longer updates. I can only see the state at the page load. Before (~ year ago) when I clicked on some button that ran some code, the new code would become "Green" but in current chrome and chromium it no longer updates and stays red (as in not executed) all the time.

index.html:

```
<button id="a">test</button>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

index.js:

```
function test() {
  // When you display code coverage it will be red
  // When you press test button, it should turn green
  console.log("this is a test");
  event.target.textContent = 'done';
}

// this will be green in code coverage
console.log("asdf");
document.getElementById('a').onclick = test;
```

Is there some settings I need to turn on?